# ElasticSearch real time GET API doesn't seem to work

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to access a doc using the GET API of ElasticSearch but eventhough the documentation claims to be real time I cannot seem to make it work.

Here's what I tried:

Indexing an event with a custom id:

```
POST: http://hostname.com:9200/events/purchase/<custom_id>
```

Immediatedly retrieving the doc using:

```
GET: http://hostname.com:9200/events/purchase/<custom_id>
```

The problem is that the document is not found.

UPDATE:

It seems that the problem only occurs if the index is initially empty and that's the first doc to be written. Subsequent requests are indexed and retrieved just fine.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about what api you are using, curl? Can you paste the curl commands that you perform?

Comment: I'm using Node's http module.

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the best code but I think this shows what you want. If possible switch to the elasticsearch.js client. That is what is used in this sample code.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var config = {host:'localhost:9200'};

var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: config.host,
    log:'trace'
});

storeEvent({"title":"My Event"}, 1);

function storeEvent(myEvent, id) {

    client.create({
        "index":"events",
        "type":"purchase",
        "id":id,
        "body":myEvent
    }, function(error,response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error during creating event");
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Submitted event");
        }
        client.get({
            "index":"events",
            "type":"purchase",
            "id":id
        }, function (error,response) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error during obtaining event");
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm doing but using the HTTP module. Even if I use this code the problem remains that I cannot get a doc immediately after it's indexed.

Comment: Maybe you can post more of your code? If I run this program it works for me. I do use a clean index, so without documents.

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? 1.2.0 had a bug involving routing: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-1-released/

If you fixed things by reindexing your data it's worth noting that it won't be compatible with future versions.